# Pygame: Is there any easy way to find the letter/number of ANY alphanumeric pressed?

Tags: python, pygame, keypress

Game I'm working on currently needs to let people time in their name for highscore board. I'm slightly familiar with how to deal with key presses, but I've only dealt with looking for specific ones. Is there an easy way to get the letter of any key pressed without having to do something like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get(): 
    if event.type == KEYUP: 
        if event.key == K_a:
           newLetter = 'a'
        elif event.key == K_b:
           newLetter = 'b'

           ...
       elif event.key == K_z:
           newLetter = 'z'
```

While that would work, I have a feeling there is a more efficient way to go about it. I just can't figure it out or find any guides on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There a basically two ways:

**Option 1:** use [`pygame.key.name()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.name).

It's as simple as

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    print(pygame.key.name(event.key))
```

The advantage over using `chr` is that `chr` works only if the value of `event.key` is between 0 and 255 (inclusive).

If you press <kbd>menu</kbd>, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>LShift</kbd>, `pygame.key.name` will happily return `menu`, `alt gr`, `tab` and `left shift`, while `chr` will crash, crash, return whitespace, and crash.

---

**Option 2:** use the `unicode` attribute of the [`pygame.KEYDOWN`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) event

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    print(event.unicode)
```

It will get you the letter/number or an empty string when using a function key, and it will also take modifiers into account, e.g. if you hold Shift while pressing a it will return `A` instead of just `a`.

> The pygame.KEYDOWN event has additional attributes unicode and
>   scancode. unicode represents a single character string that is the
>   fully translated character entered. This takes into account the shift
>   and composition keys. scancode represents the platform-specific key
>   code.

Answer (score 1):

if you look K_a is just 97 thats the ascii code for 'a' ,  I will extrapolate to K_? is the ascii code for whatever the question mark represents

```
if event.type == KEYUP: 
    print chr(event.key) #convert ascii code to a character
```

maybe?

as pointed out this will not work with ascii over 255 (no longer ascii really)

you can use the method outlined below or just use `unichr(event.key)` instead of `chr`

Comment: I recommend *not* using `chr`, as it will crash if the value of event.key` is greater than 255; especially if there's a library function that handles such cases just fine.

Comment: yeah thats a good point ... using unichr should also resolve that issue