# Pygame keys not using capital letter

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to take input to the user and then display the input on the pygame window this works fine the problem is that when i press left shift or caps it doesnt add a capital letter to my list words.

```
words = []
class Input:

    def keys(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                        words.append("A")
                    else:
                        words.append("a")

    def TextBox(self, surface, BoxColor, TextColor, Text, x,y,w,h):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 20)
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, BoxColor, (x,y,w,h))
        word = "".join(words)
        text(surface, word, TextColor, font, x,y,w,h)
        self.keys(self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each key press generates one event, so pressing shift and a generates two different events.

Look closely at your code:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_a:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
```

`event.key` can't be `pygame.K_a` *and* `pygame.K_LSHIFT` at the same time.

---

To solve your problem, take a look at [`pygame.key.get_mods`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_mods):

> **pygame.key.get_mods()**
>       *determine which modifier keys are being held*
>       `get_mods() -> int`
>
> Returns a single integer representing a bitmask of all the modifier keys being held. Using bitwise operators you can test if
>   specific shift keys are pressed, the state of the capslock button, and
>   more.

So your code should probably look like this (you'll get the idea.):

```
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            mods = pygame.key.get_mods()
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                if mods & pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT or mods & pygame.KMOD_CAPS:
                    words.append("A")
                else:
                    words.append("a")
```

---

But I guess you don't want to create an `if` block for each possible key, so you maybe want to use [`pygame.key.name()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.name) or `pygame.KEYDOWN.unicode` to read the letter directly from the event.

Take a look at [Is there any easy way to find the letter/number of ANY alphanumeric pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22997052/142637)

Answer (score 1):

You could also just append the `event.unicode` attribute.

```
import string
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
CHARACTERS = set(string.ascii_letters+string.digits+string.punctuation)
print(CHARACTERS)
words = []

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.unicode in CHARACTERS:
                words.append(event.unicode)
                print(''.join(words))

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```